# ember model function not executing when route is activated

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember route that I've stripped down to

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        console.log("model function executing");
        Ember.Object.create()
    },
    setupController: function(controller){
        console.log("setupController function executed");
    }
});
```

When I switch to MyRoute, the setupController gets executed, but the function to populate the model never does. The model ends up just being the `msg` object that was passed in the  `{{link myRoute msg}}` tag.

There are parts of the model that I need to load/compute at the time that we switch to that route. To do this I need to either be able to successfully update the model, or I need access to the params passed in the link from within the setupController function. Suggestions on how best to achieve this?

**EDIT**

To try to hash this out, I've created a complete minimal example that will produce this behavior:

my html is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> This is my Page! </title> 

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#linkTo example App.thing}}<p> go </p>{{/linkTo}}
      <div>
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <p> Initial Text </p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="example">
      <p> After change </p>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

with the app code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("example", {path: "/example/:id"});
});

App.thing = Ember.Object.create({
    id:10,
});

App.ExampleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        console.log("in model function");
        return new Ember.Object.create();
    },
    setupController: function(controller){
        console.log("in setupController");
    }
});
```

When you click on the link to the example route, "in setupController" prints, but "in model function" does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`linkTo` uses `transitionTo` behind the scenes. Whenever we use `transitionTo`, we actually provide the context/model directly and so the `model` method on the route is not called. In your example above, you have `{{#linkTo example App.thing}}`. Since we already known that the context is `App.thing` there's no reason to trigger the `model` method. We only call `model` on the route when we do not know what the model is. The main time this happens is when entering via a URL change.

Comment: Thanks, that more or less makes sense. Looking back through the docs, I see that I can also define setupController as function(controller, model) which will address the rest of my use case.

Comment: Isn't that a bit like saying if you know the URL for a webpage you don't need to bother loading it since you must already know what content is there? Knowing a url means you know some information about the total page 'model' there may be (and usually is) more information to come.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work for me, and there's absolutely no reason why it shouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/SXTME/

Are you sure you're using EMBER 1.0.0-PRE.4, and not EMBER 1.0.0-PRE.3?

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        console.log("model function executing");
        Ember.Object.create()
    },
    setupController: function(controller){
        console.log("setupController function executed");
    }
});
```

Comment: am running jquery-1.8.2.js handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js and ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js

Comment: I've got an entire functioning app that shows the behavior now.