# Ember transitioning from route prevents new record to be created

Tags: ember.js

Accessing `/documents/new/1` directly works fine, but when coming from `/documents/select` the record is already available due to the query Ember did earlier in the Select route.

**Routes**

```
this.resource('documents', function() {
  this.route('new', { path: '/new/:document_id' });
  this.route('show', { path: '/:document_id' });
  this.route('select');
});
```

**Route**

```
App.DocumentsSelectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Document.find({public: true});
  }
});

App.DocumentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
      console.log('New Model')
      var originalDoc = App.Document.find(params.document_id),
          newDoc = App.Document.createRecord();
          originalDoc.one('didLoad', function () {
               newDoc.setProperties(this.serialize());
          });
          return newDoc;
    }
});
```

`model` never gets called when coming from the Select route since the `record` already got loaded there. I found some information about this behavior but it doesn't  help my situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591851/555240

Update:
**Templates**

application.handlebars

```
<li>{{#linkTo "documents.select"}}New{{/linkTo}}</li>
```

select.handlebars

```
<ul>
{{#each doc in controller}}
  <li>
    {{#linkTo "documents.new" doc}}<div class="cover"></div>{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "documents.new" doc}}{{doc.title}}{{/linkTo}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

new.handlebars

```
{{ model }}
{{#if model.slug }}
  {{ view App.DocumentView templateNameBinding="model.slug" class="document portrait" }}
{{ else }}
  Loading...
{{/if}}
```

`{{ model }}` in `new.handlebars` show `<App.Document:ember340:1>` when transitioned to, but `<App.Document:ember304:null>` when navigated to directly.

Comment: How are you transitioning from the select route to the new route? Can you post your {{#linkTo}} or action that you are using

Comment: I added some relevant templates. Maybe it's the fact that using routes with segments in them is causing the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your resources definition you have:

```
this.route('new', { path: '/new/:document_id' });
```

This means that you have a dynamic segment in the url for new documents, so Ember is expecting that when you access the url /document/new/1 that you are going to be working with a *Document* with id 1. The default behaviour would be to retrieve a *Document* with id 1 and make it available as the model.

Typically with a RESTful structure you would have a static url like */document/new* which would create a new *Document* instead of looking up an existing one.

However if you are sure that you want to use the code DocumentsNewRoute.model function then I would suggest changing the link in the select.handlebars file.

In your select.handlebars file you have:

```
{{#linkTo "documents.new" doc}}
```

That means it is going to pass the *doc* object through as the context for DocumentsNewRoute route.  If you change this to:

```
{{#linkTo "documents.new"}}
```

Then it won't have a context, so it will execute the model function on the *DocumentsNewRoute* route. But then there won't be an id in the params to look up the model. So you could change your code to simply create a new record

ps: Are you sure you need to retrieve a *Document* from the database for this route?

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I want to achieve is to copy a "template" document to a new record, and that template is stored in the database. The new record will later be saved by the user to its own id. This was the only approach I could come up with.

Comment: I just reworked the code a bit, instead of making the new record upfront it will be done when the document is saved instead. Thanks again for getting me on better thoughts.

Comment: Just bear in mind that when you hit /document/new/1 that url means you are working with a document of id 1. I think a more RESTful approach would be to have a url of /document/new for creating a new document, then in your model method, you can load a template with a known id and assign the values to the newly created document. Basically the id in the url should refer to the document being created/edited/viewed/updated ... not the template id.